# Styles for CSS classes in an iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

Inspired by the new [User Flair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair), but the question applies to the general case as well.

Let's say I want to include something like this on a site that doesn't allow me to specify external styles or use any JavaScript code. The only thing I can do is paste in an `object`, `embed`, or `iframe`, and some other simple HTML. Additionally, the width of the space is only 160 pixels, rather than the 200 needed by default for the flair badge.

To fix this, I want to set styles for the `valuable-flair` class in the iframe, namely change width to be `160px` instead of `200px`.  Then things will be fine, as long as the username doesn't overlap (and even then, once I figure this out I can use the same technique to play with that as well).

How can it be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can alter the design of the Iframe using CSS if you can't control the page in the SRC attribute.

I recommend you read the src of the iframe on the server side instead (using PHP, Python or what you fancy), e.g. fopen() the src and fread() into a variable, than do some str_replace on this variable (to extract contents, remove < body >,< / body >...) play with the design and place the result in your page.

This way you can control the design.

Comment: And if I don't control the server code?  I have to just plug this into a cms.

Answer (score 0):

If the CSS for the width and height were expressed as percentages rather than absolute values, you could adjust the width by adjusting the IFrame.  However, if hosting a custom implementation is not possible for you, you are out of luck without JavaScript.